# Spyder does not autocomplete local variables

Tags: spyder, code-completion

I'm having a problem getting my local variables autocompleted. This is a very basic functionality which I'm sure it should support. When I'm starting to write a variable name which was already declared, and press TAB (this is the default shortcut), I get nothing. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) Spyder does complete local variables but to have this functionality you need to install a library called `rope`. You can do it by running this command in a terminal

```
pip install rope
```

If you use Python 3 this command needs to be

```
pip install rope_py3k
```

Besides, code completion on the Editor works now with both `Ctrl+Space` and with `Tab`.

**Edit**: Updated answer for the Spyder version *2.3.0*.

Comment: Great! just finished seeing your youtube video, great work guys!
I think spyder is great, would really appriciate if you could support more types in the variable explorer, such as pandas series and dataframes, multi dimensional arrays and so on.

Comment: I'm glad you saw and enjoyed my video! Dataframes and Series in the variable explorer are also planned for a future release, I just need to find the time to do it :)

Comment: Take a look at this [issue](http://http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1160). It has some starting code and ideas from which you can start off. If you questions or need orientation, please write there. I really hope you can help us with this :)

Comment: Yep, sorry. This is the [right link](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1160)

Comment: I'm on a Mac. How do I make sure when doing pip install I'm really installing it for Spyder? Right now my pip comes from miniconda (Python 3) which will just say `Requirement already satisfied`.

Comment: Spyder is not ready for Python 3 yet. Our next version (currently in beta) will support and when that happens miniconda will do it too.

Comment: Spyder 2.3.1 now has a pandas dataframe and series editor and support Python 3

Comment: Thank you very much **Carlos Cordoba**! I use `sudo pip3 install rope_py3k` instead of `sudo pip install rope_py3k` and it works too.

Comment: the tab completion works when I go `pandas.<tab>` but when i try to access the methods in a variable for e.g. df.<tab>, it does not work . . . am I doing something wrong or this is not yet a feature?

Comment: @vagabond, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42789884/438386 for an explanation.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba thanks! i'll have to create a github issue then!

Comment: As of now, rope_py3k is deprecated and rope is compatible with Python 3. So you should just go with `pip install rope`

Answer (score 4):

Another hint:

If you want to customize the shortcut (for example, your 'ctrl+space' is already occupied), try

```
Tools--Preferences--Keyboard shortcuts--code completion
```

you can change it to whatever you want

Comment: Another option (available only in the upcoming `2.3` version) is that you can use the `Tab` key to do code completions in the Editor

Answer (score 4):

**Idoda**, I made a little guide to [install Python for scientific computing on Ubuntu or Debian](https://milq.github.io/install-python-scientific-computing-ubuntu-debian) from their repositories. I tested correctly using Python 3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

It summarizes as follows. First, install the interpreter and the package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip
```

Now install the Spyder's IDE:

```
sudo apt-get install spyder3
```

Thanks to **Carlos Cordoba**'s advice, if you want to enjoy the autocomplete execute:

```
sudo pip3 install rope_py3k
```

Finally, open Spider and check if the autocomplete works rightly.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, with the command `conda install spyder`, the installation process prompted me with the following...

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

rope:   0.10.5-py36_0 conda-forge
spyder: 3.1.4-py36_0  conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

I want to point out that my anaconda installation is for python 3. After this auto-completion was working. I'm utilizing OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, ctrl+space is set to code completion in 
Tools -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts -> code completion
We have the option to change it to another shortcut.