# Spyder autocomplete doesn't work with 64-bit WinPython 2.7.5

Tags: python, spyder

In my installation of Spyder, autocomplete (ctrl+space) doesn't work in the editor (but does in the console). It looks like the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044312/spyder-does-not-autocomplete-local-variables) but I'm on Windows 7, so I can't `pip install rope` as the answer suggests.

My installation of Python is courtesy of WinPython and is version `WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.2`. It comes with Spyder 2.2.2.

I've attempted to get Spyder into debug mode with the `--debug` command line option, as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spyderlib/BvlTphgl9Jk), but it appears not to be available in this version of Spyder. (Spyder says `no such option -d`)

The follwing info may or may not be useful, from the Spyder about page:

```
Python 2.7.5 64bits, Qt 4.8.4, PyQt4 (API v2) 4.9.6 on Windows
```

Can anyone help get me going again? Without autocomplete I'm lost!

Many thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Spyder is bundled with WinPython it automatically comes with `rope` installed as part of the Spyder package. However, the Spyder 2.2.2 Windows installers shipped with the wrong version of `rope`, and code completion will not work. Fortunately, Spyder 2.2.3 has just been released, and upgrading Spyder will fix your problem. Use this procedure:

1. Download the binary installer `spyder-2.2.3.win-amd64.exe` from the [Spyder downloads page](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/downloads/list).
2. Open up the WinPython Control Panel, which can be found in the root directory of your WinPython install.
3. Drag and drop the Spyder installer into the control panel, and then hit the "Install packages" button.

You should now be able to launch Spyder from the WinPython root directory using the executable there, and code completion should be fixed.