# Why autocompletion options in Spyder 3.1 are not fully working in the Editor?

Tags: python, autocomplete, spyder

Running on Mac Sierra, the autocompletion in Spyder (from Anaconda distribution), seems quite erratic. When used from the Ipython console, works as expected. However, when used from the editor (which is my main way of writing), is erratic. The autocompletion works (i.e. when pressing TAB a little box appears showing options) for some modules, such as pandas or matplotlib. So writing 'pd.' and hitting TAB, gets the box with options as expected. However, this does not happen with many other objects: for example, after defining a dataframe named 'df', typing 'df.' TAB shows nothing. In the Ipython console, 'df.' TAB would show the available procedures for that dataframe, such as groupby, and also its columns, etc..

So the question is threefold. First, is there any particular configuration that should be enabled to get this to work? I don't think so, given some time spent googling, but just wanna make sure. Second, could someone state what is the official word on what works and what doesn't in terms of autocompletion (e.g. what particular modules do work from the editor, and which ones doesn't?). Finally, what are the technical aspects of the differences between the editor and the Ipython console in the performance of the autocompletion with Spyder? I read something about Jedi vs. PsychoPy modules, so got curious (however, please keep in mind that although I have scientific experience, I am relatively new to computation, so please keep it reasonably simple for an educated but not expert person).

UPDATE: As a side question, it would be great to know why is the autocompletion better in Rodeo (another IDE). It is more new, has way fewer overall options than Spyder, but the autocompletion works perfectly in the editor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*)

My answers:

> is there any particular configuration that should be enabled to get this to work?

In Spyder 3.1 we added the `numpydoc` library to improve completions of some objects (like Matplotlib figures and NumPy arrays). If Dataframe completions are not working for you (they are for me), please open an issue in our issue tracker on Github to track and solve this problem.

> could someone state what is the official word on what works and what doesn't in terms of autocompletion (e.g. what particular modules do work from the editor, and which ones doesn't?)

The most difficult part is getting completions of definitions when an object is generated by functions or methods developed in C/C++/Fortran and not in Python. I mean, things like

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([])
a.<TAB>
```

As I said, this should be working now for arrays, figures and dataframes, but it doesn't work for all libraries (and most scientific Python libraries are created in C/C++/Fortran and wrapped in Python for speed).

The problem is that the completion libraries we use (Rope and Jedi) can't deal with this case very well because `array` (for example) can't be introspected in a static way (i.e. without running code involving it). So we have to resort to tricks like analyzing `array`'s docstring to see its return type and introspect that instead.

> what are the technical aspects of the differences between the editor and the Ipython console in the performance of the autocompletion with Spyder?

The most important difference is that in the IPython console you **have to** run your code before getting completions about it. For example, please run this in a fresh IPython console

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df = pd.Da<Tab>
```

and you will see that it **won't** return you any completions for `Da` (when it obviously should return `Dataframe`).

But, after evaluation, it is quite simple to get completions. You can simply run

```
dir(pd)
```

to get them (that's what IPython essentially does internally).

On the other hand, Spyder's Editor doesn't have a console to run code into, so it has to get completions by running static analysis tools in your code (like Jedi and Rope). As I said, they introspect your code without running it. While they work very well for pure Python code, they have the problems I described above for compiled libraries.

And trying to evaluate the code you have in the Editor to get completions is usually not a good idea because:

1. It is not necessarily valid Python code all the time. For example, suppose you left an unclosed parenthesis somewhere, but you want to get completions at some other point. That should work without problems, right?
2. It could involve a very costly computation (e.g. loading a huge CSV in a Dataframe), so evaluating it every time to get completions (and that's a must because your code is different every time you ask for completions) could consume all your RAM in a blink.

> it would be great to know why is the autocompletion better in Rodeo (another IDE)

Last time I checked (a couple of years ago), Rodeo evaluated your code to get completions. However, we'll take a look at what they are doing now to see if we can improve our completion machinery.

Comment: Boy, this is the longest answer I've written in Stackoverflow!! I'll use it as a reference for this subject because it comes up a lot among our (frustrated) users :)

Comment: Indeed a great and comprehensive answer. Thanks a lot Carlos. One more thing: could you confirm if this is something high in the priority list for Spyder? Regarding Rodeo, last weekend I checked both IDEs thoroughly, and I have to say that their autocompletion works extremely well and efficiently. Would you mind updating back here once (if) you check what they are doing? Would be great to know if is possible to improve on Spyder or if it is definitely a core, unfixable issue. Gracias y saludos!

Comment: I'll come back to you if we can improve things by studying Rodeo's code. We also have other ideas to improve the situation. I can assure this is an important problem for us, and we have gone to great lengths to improve what Jedi and Rope provide by default. The thing is this is a very tricky problem and Spyder has a lot of other things that need attention (with debugging being perhaps the most important one), so it'll take us some time to get to a point where completion works flawlessly.

Comment: Carlos, just to be sure on the bug report: you mentioned that autocompletion should work normally for pandas. Creating some variables (say, a standard DataFrame named 'my_data' ), in the editor typing 'my_<TAB>' completes normally to 'my_data' as expected, but then 'my_data.<TAB>' does nothing. However, directly in the Ipython console, the latter does show all suggestions (such as .data.. Is this buggy behavior to file the report?

Comment: I also noted a cool feature in Rodeo: as in the example above, assume "my_data" has one column named "foo". As expected, "my_data.f<TAB>" would show the options (along with a cool box including documentation for the object). But impressively, "my_data['f<TAB>" or even 'my_data[<TAB>' will show suggestion for 'my_data['foo']'. I guess there has to be some core differences between Rodeo and Spyder. Any clues or hunches on what allows that behavior?

Comment: About the bug: `my_data.<Tab>` should return suggestions in the Editor. If that's not happening for you, that's a bug. About Rodeo: those features of completion of Dataframes are provided by IPython, so I'm almost sure they are evaluating the code you have in the Editor in an IPython kernel and getting completions from it. As I said in my answer, that's very risky. But we'll have to investigate further.

Comment: Hi @CarlosCordoba, have you looked into this ? I'm using Windows 11/Python 3.10.9/Spyder 5.4, and my_data.<Tab> does not return suggestions in the Editor. Nor does my_data.add( show any calltip. Both those things work in the IPython console, though. Relating to ewadaniela's answer, I do have white spaces in the path to the python interpreter. Is this a problem ?
Thanks for your great work. :)

Comment: Sorry, we haven't had enough man power to take a look at this.

Answer (score 5):

Autocompletion  works correctly if there are NO white spaces in the project working directory path.

Answer (score 5):

Autocomplete was not working for me at all. 
So, I tried Tools -> Reset Sypder to factory defaults and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me as well!