# Code autocompletion 'partially' works in the editor pane of Spyder3

Tags: python, autocomplete, spyder

I installed spyder3 through miniconda3 on my win10 PC. Autocompletion works perfectly in the Ipython console pane but not in the editor pane.
In the editor pane it only list partial completion options when I use <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

[image]

This is my Editor preferences settings which is almost default.

[image]

Should Editor pane's auto completion ability be 'weaker' than that of Ipython pane in Spyder3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) It's a true and sad reality, but our Editor can't show the same completions that are available to the IPython console.

I explained in [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789884/438386) why that's the case. Basically, it's not our fault, it's just a limitation of the code completion libraries we use in the Editor (Rope and Jedi).

Comment: I really appreciate the efforts you made to maintain Spyder anyway!

Comment: Thanks for your kind words!