# How do I add intellisense to anaconda spyder?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I'm new to Machine Learning and using Spyder. I'm on Python 3.6. How do I add intellisense to Spyder so when I type a class or method name I will see a list of available options? I checked my Preferences tab but didn't see anything. Could've missed it though. Also, my Preferences are listed under the Python window(see below)

[Preferences Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEzXm.png)

I've heard of the Preferences option being located under the Help menu but didn't see anything.

Comment: Intellisense is specific to Visual Studio, you cannot install it (as far as I know) in Spyder

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, Spyder can't provide code completion for all Python objects. This is not a failure in Spyder but a limitation in Python, due to its dynamic nature. Sorry.

Comment: Ah darn. The guy in the video tutorial I'm learning from is using code completion, so I thought it was possible.

Comment: You should type 'pip install rope_py3k' in terminal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044312/spyder-does-not-autocomplete-local-variables @newcoder

Answer (score 2):

1. Run Anaconda Prompt.
2. At the prompt "`activate yourenvironmentyouwantintellisense`"
3. You should now see your environment name in parentheses.
4. type `pip install rope_py3k`
5. Close out of everything and reopen anaconda, making sure you are using the correct environment.
6. Enjoy intellisense.